# TYPO3 8.1: Generate Images only when needed

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Currently I'm building a website with TYPO3 (version 8.1.2 at the moment), that has a lot of very large images. I'm using the extension TYPO3 bootstrap package and modified it to my needs including the image view helper which currently looks like this:

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width:1600px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(image: file)}">
    <source media="(min-width:1200px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1600)}, {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 3200)} 2x">
    <source media="(min-width:992px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1200)}, {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 2400)} 2x">
    <source media="(min-width:768px)" srcset="{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 992)}, {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1984)} 2x">
    <img class="img-responsive" srcset="{f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 768)}, {f:uri.image(image: file, maxWidth: 1536)} 2x">
</picture>
```

The problem with this setup is that if the different files are not created yet, e.g. if the page is viewed for the first time after adding a new image, TYPO3 has a lot of number-crunching to do to generate all the different versions of the image at different sizes and that takes way too long (more than one minute).

So, what I'm looking for is one of two possible solutions:

1. A way to tell TYPO3 to render a particular image as late as possible (i.e. when that particular file is requested by the browser ant not when the page is rendered by TYPO3) or
2. a way to use ajax to request only the size of an image that is actually needed, e.g. modify my ViewHelper to something like this:
   `<img data-uid="{file.propertiesOfFileReference.uid}">`
   and then have some javascript-code determine the size that I actually need and request the image at exactly that size (for caching purposes maybe in steps of 200px). The js-part of this should be pretty easy to do, but I have no idea how to implement the typo3-part. There are some explanations about typo3 and ajax to be found on different sites, but I have no clue how recent those are and to achieve what I need, I'd have to call a view helper that renders the image for me, and I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me if one of these two solutions is even possible?

Comment: Maybe this extension could help you: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/lef_responsive_images. On the other hand - if your pages aren't dynamic, you could set up a crawler task to pre-render all contents.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a third solution, that is to create a scheduler job which would be "caching" these images before the page reload. You can even use FAL to track if the image has been somehow manipulated and refresh cache. There are different approaches on choosing which images to cache, but the easiest might be to force editors to simply put all images they would be using inside one specific folder/filemount (with subfolders of course) and cron job would just go through them and generate all the sizes needed.